# How do I take the result from a message box?

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010), if this is used for giving a message,

```
MsgBox("hello", 4, "status")
```

how do I manipulate the result *Yes* or *No* from the msgbox?

Like this should happen if the user gives *No* and this should happen if *No*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check whether `MsgBox` returned `vbYes`.

For example:

```
If vbYes = MsgBox("hello", vbYesNo, "status") Then
    'Do things
Else
    'Don't do things
End If
```

Comment: Why would you write vbYes = MsgBox(...) instead of MsgBox(...) = vbYes?  Reformed C programmer?

Comment: @Jason: No.  I write it that way because MessageBox / MsgBox calls get very long, and I don't want to need to scroll to the right to see the comparison.

Comment: Ah - that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

[MsgBox Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Lesson 10: Introduction to VB Built-in Functions](http://www.vbtutor.net/lesson10.html)

Sample code:

```
Private Sub Test_Click()

    Dim testMsg As Integer

    testMsg = MsgBox("Click to test", 1, "Test message")


    If testMsg = 1 Then                    'User clicked on OK button
       Display.Caption = "Test Succeeded"
    Else                                   'User clicked on Cancel button
       Display.Caption = "Test failed"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can just do this also:

```
Dim response As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Are You Sure you want to delete this entry?", MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 Or MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Warning")



 If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
```