# Error Code 424 when trying to set a value based on a message box response

Tags: vba, ms-access, setvalue

I have been trying to get this to work but I do not see the issue with it.
My form is called "Request_Order" and the Yes/No checkbox is called "Processed"

```
Private Sub MarkProcessedOrig_Click()
Const cstrPrompt As String = _
    "Are you sure you want to mark this request as processed? Yes/No"

If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Request_Order.Controls(Processed).Value = True
Else: Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: According to my research, you can refer to this post:
[How do I take the result from a message box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983135/how-do-i-take-the-result-from-a-message-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to delete ‘Request_Order’, this is not necessary, it will run successfully after deletion.

Please try the code below:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Const cstrPrompt As String = _
            "Aref'jei you sure you want to mark this request as processed? Yes/No"

        If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Controls("CheckBox1").Value = True
        Else: Cancel = True
        End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you for the help!

Comment: Would it be possible to add a string so that if "CheckBox1" = True already, it can display a different message box that tells the user this checkbox has already been requested?

Comment: @GantoranAs far as I understand, you want to add a message box, like this： `MsgBox ("checkBox has already been requested")` right? Or you can create a new post detailing the circumstances under which you want to inform the user. For example, when the user selects the check box, the user is told that the check box has been requested.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Collection elements are identified by the name of the element, which is a string, or by the offset, which is an integer. So you need to do this:

```
Request_Order.Controls("Processed").Value = True
```

The error you're getting is that the VBA runtime can't parse your statement as an object, because your code is saying that there's a variable called `Processed` that evaluates to a string, and that that variable is a assigned a string value that is the name of one of the controls in your collection. Since that isn't true, you get this error.